# Transparency not working suddenly?

Tags: transparency

[image]
Last I checked this was how to make a png alpha. Help, please.

Comment: Maybe 'alpha' set to one?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the image alpha node connected to the alpha node on principled shader. connected that and it fixed the problem.